# How to run a query on multiple instances and databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I want to automate index rebuilding or reorganize on multiple instances and databases using powershell. I have the query below:

```bsh
$SQLInstances = "Server1", "Server2", "Server3"


$Databses = "Db1", "Db2", "Db3"

  
Foreach ($SQLInstance in $SQLInstances) {

            foreach ($DbName in $Databses)
        {
    
            Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Database $DBName -Query $IndexQuery
        }

}
```

The $IndexQuery variable's value is

```sql
USE master
                        EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize @Databases = '$DBName',
                        @FragmentationLow = NULL,
                        @FragmentationMedium = 
                       'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
                        @FragmentationHigh = 
                         'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
                        @FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
                        @FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
                        @UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
                        @OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'
```

For some reasons this code is not working. It runs without error but its not doing rebuilding or re-organize the indexes. The issue is not with the sql query because it runs fine in SSMS but the problem is my powershell script. Any Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "not doing anything to the indexes"? What is the value of `$IndexQuery`? What is the goal of said SQL in `$IndexQuery`?

Comment: @Larnu I have edited my question. That variable contains sql query that calls stored procs but the issue isnt the sql part, its the nested foreachloop

Comment: Looks like you're using Ola Halengren's scripts. You can already specify multiple databases in the `Databases` parameter. You don't need the loop at all

Comment: Where do you define `$IndexQuery`? As written it can only work correctly if it is assigned *within* the loop (so `$DBName` gets replaced).

Comment: OP is trying to do multiple databases *and* servers though, @PanagiotisKanavos .

Comment: @Larnu it's using the same names for each instance, so the inner loop can be removed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but how can that be done since I want this to run on multiple databases sitting on different instances

Comment: Set the log to table option and see what the output is like.